# PHP Array GET parent and child

Tags: php

Hello I Have this Array from a dataset:

Example:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => ' Category',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
    'name' => ' Slippers',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '3',
    'name' => ' TShirts',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '4',
    'name' => ' BlousesSweatshirt',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '5',
    'name' => ' Cap',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
    'name' => ' Stickers',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => '7',
    'name' => ' ScreensandFrames',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',
    'name' => ' Models',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'id' => '9',
    'name' => ' Notebook',
    'id_parent' => '6',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'id' => '10',
    'name' => ' Door',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'id' => '11',
    'name' => ' Door',
    'id_parent' => '6',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'id' => '12',
    'name' => ' Kangaroo',
    'id_parent' => '4',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'id' => '13',
    'name' => ' KangarooRaglan',
    'id_parent' => '4',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'id' => '14',
    'name' => ' RoundCollar',
    'id_parent' => '4',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'id' => '15',
    'name' => ' Trucker',
    'id_parent' => '5',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'id' => '16',
    'name' => ' Basic',
    'id_parent' => '3',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'id' => '17',
    'name' => ' Longline',
    'id_parent' => '3',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'id' => '18',
    'name' => ' Raglan',
    'id_parent' => '3',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'id' => '19',
    'name' => ' Raglan3/4',
    'id_parent' => '3',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  20 => 
  array (
    'id' => '20',
    'name' => ' Regatta',
    'id_parent' => '3',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'id' => '21',
    'name' => ' Slide',
    'id_parent' => '2',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    'id' => '22',
    'name' => ' Stickers',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  23 => 
  array (
    'id' => '23',
    'name' => ' Notebook',
    'id_parent' => '22',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  24 => 
  array (
    'id' => '24',
    'name' => ' T-shirt',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  25 => 
  array (
    'id' => '25',
    'name' => ' Basic',
    'id_parent' => '24',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  26 => 
  array (
    'id' => '26',
    'name' => ' Slippers',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  27 => 
  array (
    'id' => '27',
    'name' => ' Slide',
    'id_parent' => '26',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  28 => 
  array (
    'id' => '28',
    'name' => ' 1Screen',
    'id_parent' => '7',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  29 => 
  array (
    'id' => '29',
    'name' => ' Set3Screens',
    'id_parent' => '7',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  30 => 
  array (
    'id' => '30',
    'name' => ' Set5Screens',
    'id_parent' => '7',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  31 => 
  array (
    'id' => '31',
    'name' => ' BlousesSweatshirt',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  32 => 
  array (
    'id' => '32',
    'name' => ' Cap',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
  33 => 
  array (
    'id' => '33',
    'name' => ' ScreensandFrames',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Whereas this array we have  fathers and childs,

example:

-EX:[1] Models is father of: Stickers, T-shirt, Slippers

-EX:[2] Stickers is father of: Notebook

What I need is a function to get Model and all Childrens (till end) recursively:

I've already done a function to get Recursive Fathers from the Notebook, for example:

here:

```
function returnParent($id, $haystack, $arr = null){

    $needle = $haystack[$id];

    $arr[] = $needle;

        if($needle['id_parent']){
            return returnParent($needle['id_parent'], $haystack, $arr);
        }else{
            return $arr;
        }
}
```

where `$id = 23` and `$haystack` is complete dataset.

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [name] => Notebook
            [id_parent] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [name] => Stickers
            [id_parent] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => models
            [id_parent] => 0
        )

)
```

The result of function to return childrens needs to be the same of returnParent, the looked up value need to be in array as key 0;

complete dataset here:
https://pastebin.com/jgTM7aLA

suggestions to make my function better is very wellcome :)

---

EDIT

Expected output:

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '8',
    'name' => ' Models',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),

  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
    'name' => ' Stickers',
    'id_parent' => '0',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),

  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '9',
    'name' => ' Notebook',
    'id_parent' => '6',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),

  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '24',
    'name' => ' T-shirt',
    'id_parent' => '8',
    'ativo' => '1',
  ),

  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '25',
    'name' => ' Basic',
    'id_parent' => '24',
    'ativo' => '1',
  )... and ..etc
```

Something like that, the key 0 must be the searched value, and the others values, dont need to be in tree order, any order its ok, as long as get all values.

in other words:

get a array node, show him and all childrens and grandchildrens.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Are you asking for a function to output the parent and then its children in the given format?

Comment: @Andreas Expected output added!

Comment: @Krishanu, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function returnChild($id, $haystack, $arr = []){

$needle = $haystack[$id];
array_push($arr, $needle);
foreach($haystack as $key){
    if($key['id_parent'] == $needle['id']){
        array_push($arr,returnChild($key['id'], $haystack));
    }
}
return $arr;
}
```

I hope this is the solution to your problem!

Comment: very close, what i need but need to return: T-shirt and his childeren Basic,
Slippers and his childeren  Slide,
BlousesSweatshirt,,
Cap,
ScreensandFrames,  in other words.. everything under Models

Comment: look this image everything under id 8 "modelos" https://paste.pics/018ae28d239f1452a01e9b2fdeda2ff1

Comment: so you want the child nested to the parent?

Comment: All childs and grandchilds (an so on..) nested to the parent.

Comment: Post edited, I think this is what you were asking for!

Comment: Nice work! And thank you for solving it. It was driving me mad. I have been working on it since question was posted. But I think I'm really close now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for.
I loop the unique parents and find what items have a matching parent.
I had to add a "NULL" value to parents and IDs because your array is not zero indexed.
That took me a long time to figure out...

Anyways the return is a 'parent' array and children below.

```
$temp = array_column($arr, "id");
$ids[0] = "NULL";
$ids = array_merge($ids, $temp);

$temp = array_column($arr, "id_parent");
$parents[0] = "NULL";
$parents = array_merge($parents, $temp);


Foreach(array_unique($parents) as $parent){
    if($parent ==0) continue; // if parent is 0 we don't need to search for it (I think)
    $new[$parent]['parent'] = $arr[$parent];
    $new[$parent]['children'] = array_intersect_key($arr, array_intersect($parents, [$parent]));
}
Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/Fbet4

Comment: I'ts very close what I need. I realy thank you for your effort,... what i need for ex: Models.. need to show grandchildrens too. .. in other words.. everything under Models.